# The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found

Tags: .net-core, jwt

Trying to add Jwt authentification to my DotNetCore 2.1 Server and Angular 6 App.

I've seen so many articles on the topic and no one seem's to do it the same way and nothing seem's to work for me either... i dont know what's wrong...

i'm getting : 'The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found.' when i start my server...

**Services**

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:54523",
             ValidAudience = "http://localhost:4300",
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("tokensecret))
        };
   });

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .Build();
    });
});

services.AddMvc();
```

**Configurations**

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseMvc();
```

**Controllers**

```
[Authorize()]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ProjectController : Controller
```

If i use the Controller [Authorize], when the user is not authentificated it return to /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...

but it's JWT it should return 401, 403 only...

if i try with     [Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] i'm getting 'The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found.'

but why...

**EDIT**

I didn't know that line was changeing the behaviour of authentification but I also use this line

```
serviceCollection.AddIdentity<User, Role>();
```

What's wrong ?
We cannot use Identity with JWT ?
how to configure it for JWT ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the way to get it working... finally!

You need to use  AddIdentityCore instead of AddIdentity.
Then you need to configure it yourself and add the missings services that are not registered in AddIdentityCore.

link to AddIdentityCore method : https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/9b385180a9abcb264507efc23279f083bfc50520/src/Core/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

**Identity Registration Code**

```
        var builder = serviceCollection.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            opt.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        });

        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(Role), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AmiliaContext>();
        builder.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        builder.AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>();
        builder.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>();
        builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>();

        serviceCollection.AddDependencies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

**Additionnal Notes**

User must inherit  IdentityUser
Role must inherit IdentityRole

You must not use SignInAsync from the SignInManager, instead you need to use CheckPasswordSignInAsync.

Why ?

Because SignInAsync is using the cookie internaly so we cannot use this method in JWT.